# Running sidekiq jobs against more than one database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, sidekiq

I have one Rails app, which uses different databases depending on the domain name (ie. it supports multiple websites). This works by loading up different environments, without issue.

I am trying to figure out how to run the same set of Sidekiq jobs for each of them.

Sidekiq runs on a worker-server instance.

I have tried running a second instance of sidekiq on the commandline of the worker, giving it a different pidfile, logfile, environment and config file.

Problem 1: In the Dashboard, all recurring tasks listed in first instance of sidekiq's config file are gone and only the task from my 2nd instance's config file is there on the `recurring jobs` tab.

Problem 2: For that job, if I try to enqueue it, I get `unitialized constant uninitialized constant JofProductUpdateLive` -> I am guessing this is because I defined the class in `app/jobs/jof_product_update_live.rb` on worker, and it is seeking it on master server ?

Problem 3: If my theory for the error is correct and I place that file on master server, seems to me it will run with `environment/db1` and i'm not sure how to run it with `db2/environment2` ?

I'm seeking any advice as to how to set something like this up, as I have tried every idea that came my way and as of yet, zero success. I have also combed through every forum I could find on sidekiq to no avail.

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Apartment gem and apartment-sidekiq.

https://github.com/influitive/apartment-sidekiq

Comment: Thanks Mike - will check that out! In the meantime, I actually got a "non-elegant" version of what my post describes working with Sidekiq alone; the key was in setting the environment name in the redis namespace.